# In Verilog can I use the same wire as both an input and output to a module

Tags: verilog

This is what I mean:

```
module someModule(~);
wire w;
someOtherModule m0 (.input(w), .output(w));
endmodule
```

Would something like this be legal?

Comment: https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/design-software/verilog/ver_bidirec.html

Comment: @EugeneSh. That isn't what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Why wouldn't it be? How else would you do feedback?

For example, to make a DFF toggle on every clock, you connect the not-Q output directly to the D input.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very common. Just be sure you don’t create a combinatorial feedback loop. I.e. if `output` was defined in the module as:

```
assign output = ~input;
```

This would effectively create an oscillator.